# How can I install debug build of AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

How can I install a debug build of Android 5.0 AOSP on my Nexus Device? Where do I get the debug build? I tried Googling but still can't find step-by-step instructions to download and install debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pull down AOSP in source form and build it for the desired Nexus target (assuming it is supported).  Start here:

http://source.android.com/source/requirements.html

Once you are setup, look into the details of building for a specific device, found here:

http://source.android.com/source/running.html

Note that if you load your device with a custom image you'll be voiding any warranty, etc.  Also, you probably don't want a full debug build, it will be very large and most likely not loadable on the device.  You'll want an "eng" build, which has a reasonable amount of debug capability in place, even for system processes and frameworks.

Good luck!